# How to convert video(mp4) file into audio(mp3) file while uploading video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter-3

I need to convert the user uploaded video file into an audio format(preferably mp3) file, using javascript(client-side) before sending it to the PHP server.

Comment: Given your tags it's not clear if you're trying to do this in JS on the client, or in CodeIgniter/PHP on the server. Please specify. In either case your question is too broad for anyone to help you effectively. Please show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg to do this on all platforms. https://ffmpeg.org/

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -vn output_audio.mp3
```

Note that this reencodes the audiostream and is therefore slower than directly extracting it with a more specific command, depending on codecs used.